# any conic in $\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

Exercise 3.1 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry:

Show that any conic in $\mathbb{A}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$ or $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$.

when the conic given by $x^{2}+y^{2}-1$, what the coordinate ring of this one? Maybe $k[x]$?
Cause I can project the circle to the affine line by deleted one point. But in topology they are not isomorphism. Then what the coordinate ring of circle?

Thanks advanced!

Comment: By definition, it is $k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$. by the ideal you can get rid of any higher powers of $y$, so each element has a unique representative of the form $\alpha y+f(x)$ with $\alpha\in k$, $f(x)\in k[x]$.